# Log into Office365 and Azure with different email addresses

Tags: microsoft-office, azure

My Azure (MSDN-based) account is tied to a different email address than my Office 365 account. I'm finding it impossible to login to one if previous browser sessions had been logged into the other. I'm having to delete cookies to achieve authentication. <strike>Need a work around badly.</strike> Need something beside the bad workaround of using different browsers. ;)

No offense intended to Mr. Gannon's suggestion - I get that it's probably the best to be had for most situations.

I'd like to try barking up a different tree - is the conflict 'cookie-based'? I'm thinking it'd have to be since all browser's i've tried show the same problem - if so, can't a commandline or bit of javascript simply delete one or the other's cookies?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding it preferable to use Privacy mode (private browsing / incognito) for Azure.

Comment: Roger that! Go private mode, the Azure "management interface" is apparently at https://manage.windowsazure.com/ which throws you to some looong URL based in "login.microsoftonline.com". (Using the "login.microsoftonline.com" URL directly won't work at all and will ferry you off to Office365-land). After entering Azure creds the screen says "login failed". Click on "Sign in with Microsoft account". The screen morphs, you end up at https://login.live.com/ and it says "Sign in to Azure". Enter credentials again.  You arrive at https://manage.windowsazure.com, but logged in ... the mind boggles.

Answer (score 1):

Use different browsers for Office365 and Azure.

Comment: If using Chromium-derived browser, you can use built-it profiles to achieve this.

Comment: That is good information. I use Chrome for Office365 webapp but Internet Explorer for SharePoint. I wonder if Azure is more friendly than SharePoint to non-IE browsers.

Comment: Since more ppl inside MS nowadays use Chrome than IE, I suspect, yes, Azure is at least not-webkit-hostile ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it is so frustrating.

Try adding your O365 user to the Azure admins and let us know if you managed to do so as I had problems doing this but finally managed it though in the process, the user that created the BizSpark Azure account lost access some how that I've yet to figure out.